# Sinatra with multiple environment config

Tags: ruby, sinatra, environments

After working with Sinatra a couple of weeks I reached the moment to deploy my app in a staging environment. After reviewing [sinatra configuration settings](http://sinatrarb.com/configuration.html) and looking around I did not find a way to have a config file per environment so that instead of having this:

```rb
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'sinatra/custom_logger'

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  helpers Sinatra::CustomLogger

  configure :development do
    logger = MyCustomLogger::Logger.new(param1, 
                                        param2, 
                                        param3,
                                        paramX)
    set :logger, logger
    ...
  end

  configure :production do
    logger = MyAnotherCustomerLogger.new(param1, param2)
    set :logger, logger
  end

  configure :whatever do

  end

  # endpoints definition
end
```

I would like to get to something cleaner like:

```rb
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'environment_config'

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  register EnvironmentConfig # Not sure how..

  ...
end

class EnvironmentConfig
  configuration :development do
    # 10 lines of configuration
  end

  configuration: production do
    # 20 lines of configuration
  end
end
```

And within that class/module we can either have a file per environment or one file with all the different configurations.

My question then would be, is there a way to structure a Sinatra app in a way that the configuration is not on the same place as the definitions of the endpoints?
Thank you beforehand.

Comment: Sinatra's `sinatra_contrib` includes the `config_file` extension that lets you decouple this to some extent - https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/sinatra-contrib/lib/sinatra/config_file.rb - though it won't let you do conditional `require`s etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response. ConfigFile allows you to export config to a yaml file, but not adding ruby code in there. I'm going to change my question to show which is my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally came up with a solution using self.included class method:

```rb
# config.rb
require 'sinatra/custom_logger'

module Config
  def self.included(base_klass)
    base_klass.extend(ClassMethods)

    base_klass.helpers(Sinatra::CustomLogger)

    base_klass.class_eval do
      configure :development do
        logger = MyCustomLogger.new(
          param1,
          param2,
          param3,
          paramx
        )


        set :logger, logger
      end

      configure :production do
        # other stuff
      end
    end
  end

  module ClassMethods; end
end
```

then

```rb
require_relative 'config'

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  include Config
```

Answer (score 1):

try sinatra/config, you can store all your config settings in a file and provide specific environment configuration.

```
require "sinatra"
require "sinatra/contrib"

config_file '../config/config.yml'

get "/"
  settings.bar
end

#config.yml
development:
  foo: development
  bar: bar
test:
  foo: test
  bar: bar
production:
  foo: production
  bar: bar
```

http://sinatrarb.com/contrib/config_file

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I'm looking for a place to put also ruby code, like Rails has with the development.rb files instead of yaml files that only allows you to have key-value config.